# Is it possible to show tasks for single project in visual studio 2010?

Tags: visual-studio-2010

I have number of projects in one visual studio solution and want to see tasks for one of them. Is it possible to do this in better way then search "//TODO"?

Upd:I know that there is a "Task List" (Ctrl+W,T) to show all tasks, question is how to display tasks for one project.

Comment: Are you asking how to filter the Task List Ctrl + W, T?

Comment: Not sure what do you mean by "search //TODO". All TODO comments can be seen in Task List, but I'm not sure, if they are filtered by project.

Comment: By "search //TODO" I meant to search it with "find and replace" (Ctrl+F)

Answer (score 0):

Just saw this while looking for a different problem.

Answer is yes you can.

In the task list window, hover over the Project header. A filter icon appears. Click it. Uncheck "all" then check the project(s) you want to view.